# Controlling Wildfly undeploy

Tags: deployment, wildfly

We have an issue with undeploying an enterprise archive from Wildfly in a controlled matter. So the issue is that we automatically undeploy and deploy a new enterprise archive to Wildfly (Wildfly is also restarted). However, the issue is that we need to make sure that system goes down in a controlled matter so that state is not lost of corrupted.

This is normally done with a shutdown-hook, but that does not work well with Wildfly. When undeploy executes the shutdown-hook is executed, but Wildfly will not respect it. It will not give enough time to system to do clean up and threads to terminate.

So is there anyway to pause the undeploy or force Wildfly wait longer for the system to terminate before killing it?

Comment: That doesn't seem like the right usage for a shutdown hook to me. A shutdown hook will not execute until the JVM is shutting down which is not the same as an undeploy. What is it you execute in the shutdown hook? What version of WildFly are you using?

Comment: We use Wildfly 20. The reason we tried to shutdown hook is that we had issues with state being lost that was supposed to be persisted. The only other way around that would have been to use a XA-transaction - which we really do not want to use.

Comment: Have you tried something like a singleton EJB and a @PreDestroy?